# Add a typeclass constraint on a Record type

Tags: haskell

Before this declaration was working well in my context :

```
data PersistedCommand = PersistedCommand { offset :: Offset , command :: Command }

instance Show PersistedCommand where
  show persistedCommand = "PersistedCommand { offset = " ++ ( show $ offset persistedCommand) ++ " , command = " ++ (show $ getCommandName $ command persistedCommand) ++ ":"
    ++ (show $ getAggregateId $ command persistedCommand) ++ " }"
```

But I've changed `Command` from a data type to a type class. How do I express this now in the previous declaration ?

Comment: `data PersistedCommand a = PersistedCommand { offset :: Offset , command :: a}` and add the constraints in the function signatures, like: `Command a => PersistentCommand a -> ...`.

Comment: can't we do better than that ?

Comment: I don't get what is "bad" with that. Typeclasses are a meta-level higher than types, so it makes sense not to start mixing these.

Comment: I agree with @WillemVanOnsem.  If you tell us more about what interface you are trying to provide to users of `PersistedCommand`, we might be able to offer some other options.

Comment: @NicolasHenin: you can use `DatatypeContexts`, but for good reasons, these are now deprecated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438600/datatypecontexts-deprecated-in-latest-ghc-why

Comment: yeah I have seen that, I'm confused why you don't see the need of it. My persisted command need to be serializable, having some specific functions like getAgreggateId /getCommandId etc....Everywhere I'm using it

Comment: maybe it's my OOP background that fools me....

Comment: I guess it _is_ your OOP background that fools you. “Changed `Command` from a data type to a type class” sounds quite fishy; data types and type classes serve two rather fundamentally different needs.  I think you should probably stay with a `data Command`, but without more code it's hard to be sure.

Comment: I wanted to decoupled the concept of Command from the examples of commands you could have... at the beginning it was funny to put all my commands in a sum type, but I realized it was becoming fishy and that command is more a typeclass that a datatype.

Comment: I have added some code around to help...

Comment: https://wiki.haskell.org/Data_declaration_with_constraint

Comment: from what I understand I could do it with the GADTs form but I would have to give up the record type syntax

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825878/type-constraints-in-data-declaration-haskell

Comment: I want to guarantee the integrity of my data lol is it so bad ? I'm thinking encapsulation in a way... I have the same reasoning that the guy in the stack-overflow link

Comment: basically you are saying to me that encapsulation should be a convention more than something enforced by the language

Comment: Plugging one of my older answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292576/haskell-how-to-cast-a-data-type-to-one-of-its-specific-typeclass/50293231#50293231 - this is a common problem to have. The answer isn't typeclasses it's rethinking how you structure your data types.

Comment: That is, if you actually need dynamism. If you don't... just use typeclasses the intended way. Have a `Command a` and slap a `(DoesWhatIWant a) => ...` constraint everywhere you need it.