# Haskell create functor with type constraints

Tags: haskell, functor

I have this Haskell code fragment:

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

module LatticePoint 
where

import Data.List    

data (Eq v) => LatticePoint v = LatticePoint{prob::Double, value::v}

instance Functor LatticePoint where
    fmap :: (Eq a, Eq b) => (a -> b) -> LatticePoint a -> LatticePoint b 
    fmap f lp = LatticePoint {prob = prob lp, value = f $ value lp}
```

On compilation I get the following error, which I don't understand

```
src/LatticePoint.hs:12:14: error:
    • No instance for (Eq a)
      Possible fix:
        add (Eq a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            fmap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> LatticePoint a -> LatticePoint b
    • When checking that instance signature for ‘fmap’
        is more general than its signature in the class
        Instance sig: forall a b.
                      (Eq a, Eq b) =>
                      (a -> b) -> LatticePoint a -> LatticePoint b
           Class sig: forall a b.
                      (a -> b) -> LatticePoint a -> LatticePoint b
      In the instance declaration for ‘Functor LatticePoint’
   |
12 |     fmap ::  (Eq a, Eq b) => (a -> b) -> LatticePoint a -> LatticePoint b 
   | 

         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for LatticePoint to be restricted to any type v which is an instance of Eq, and to make LatticePoint an instance of Functor.

Comment: You aren't allowed to constrain the type of `fmap` further.

Comment: Typically, you don't add constraints to data types, but to the functions that use them. `data LatticePoint v = ...; foo :: Eq a => LatticePoint a -> Whatever`.

Comment: See also [Type Constraints in Data Declaration Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40825878/791604).

Comment: See also [Edward Kmett - Type Classes vs. the World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIZxTQP1ifo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `LatticePoint` is not a [`Functor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor). A `Functor` is defined to state "For *every* pair of types `a` and `b`, I can lift a function `a -> b` to a function `f a -> f b`". You can't provide an instance that only works for a few types, or for some but not all. This is the same reason [`Set`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Set.html) is not a functor, since all nontrivial operations on it require `Ord` on the element type.

Before we can use an alternative to `Functor`,  we will actually need to take some advice from the comment section of this post. As pointed out, in Haskell, it's typical to not constrain a datatype itself but to merely constrain all functions that act on it (the feature allowing datatype constraints is largely considered a misfeature and its use is discouraged). So rather than putting the `Eq` constraint in the `data` line, it's more idiomatic to leave the `data` line an ordinary declaration and constrain every function that takes or produces a `LatticePoint`.

This is because, if you constrain the datatype directly, it's not even *meaningful* to say `LatticePoint a` for every `a`, which makes it much harder to reason about types (every time you want to mention your type in any context, you effectively need to accompany it with a proof of correctness). But if the `LatticePoint a` type is *well-defined* for every `a` but just happens to be useless and unconstructible for some of them, it's much easier to reason about our types. So I'll assume our declaration is

```
data LatticePoint v = LatticePoint{prob::Double, value::v}
```

We can approximate what you want with [`MonoFunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.15.3/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFunctor). `MonoFunctor` provides a much weaker constraint. It says "Given some definition of 'element type' for our container, I can lift functions on elements to functions on the container type". Crucially, we never said it had to work for *all* types, just for types which the container says are valid "elements".

```
type instance Element (LatticePoint a) = a
```

Now we can write our `MonoFunctor` instance.

```
instance Eq a => MonoFunctor (LatticePoint a) where
  omap :: (a -> a) -> LatticePoint a -> LatticePoint a
  omap f latticePoint = ...
```

You'll note one thing here: our function has to map from `a` to `a`. It can't map to a different target type, even if both the source and target are `Eq`. This is simply a restriction of `MonoFunctor`, and I'm not aware of any typeclass that allows `MonoFunctor`-style class constraints *and* allows maps which are not endomorphisms.

Answer (score 4):

Converting my comments to an answer, you typically defer the constraints to the functions that *use* `LatticePoint` in a context where the value requires an `Eq` constraint. This lets you define `fmap`.

```
module LatticePoint 
where

import Data.List    

data LatticePoint v = LatticePoint{prob::Double, value::v}

instance Functor LatticePoint where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> LatticePoint a -> LatticePoint b 
    fmap f lp = LatticePoint {prob = prob lp, value = f $ value lp}

foo :: Eq a => LatticePoint a -> Whatever
foo lp = ...
```

If you think about it, the data structure *itself* doesn't care whether `value` can be compared for equality, only functions that *use* the data structure.

As a concrete example, consider a definition of `(==)` itself:

```
instance Eq a => Eq (LatticePoint a) where
    (LatticePoint p1 v1) == (LatticePoint p2 v2) = p1 == p2 && v1 == v2
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I even remember looking at that after I typed it and thinking something looked off, but I couldn't put my finger on what it was.